# Using Regex to separate Asian market numerical stock tickers

Tags: regex, stockquotes

Pulling some trading data and having issues using regex to separate tickers and percentage of holding

**Inputs**

"94324.13%"

"007007.13%"

"0354202.91%"

**Desired Output**

"9432|4.13%" (ticker is 4 numbers)

"00700|7.13%" (ticker is 5 numbers)

"035420|2.91%" (ticker is 6 numbers)

Main issue is that the number of digits the ticker is may vary anywhere from 4-6  digits.

Comment: Do you have any way of knowing how long the tickers are or the other part is?

Comment: Where is the regex, you have tried so far?

Comment: In which language are you using? Javascript, python, php etc?

Comment: Unless you know how long the ticker is, or can assume how long the % suffix is, you cannot umabiguously parse this data. eg.something like "654321.09%" may be a a 4 or 5 digit ticker, etc.

Answer (score 1):

With the given information it is not possible to have a 100% accurate split of the two parts. For instance:

```
123410.05%
```

... could split in either of the following two:

```
1234|10.05%
12341|0.05%
```

And if percentages might not have a zero before the decimal point, then this would also be a possible split:

```
123410|.05%
```

The following regex replace will assume the percentage has one digit before the decimal point, and possibly a minus sign:

Find:

```
/^(\d{4,6})(\-?\d.*)$/gm
```

Replace:

```
\1|\2
```

See it on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/fN2bA0/2).

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to try this regex

```
(\d{4,6})(\d+\.\d{1,2}%)
```

Here is full demo:

> Python:

```
data = "007007.13%"
rx = re.compile(r"(\d{4,6})(\d+\.\d{1,2}%)")
formated_text = rx.sub(r'\1|\2', data)
print formated_text

#it will print
00700|7.13%
```

You can look demo in python [here](https://regex101.com/r/sC4pR4/1)

> Javascript:

```
var re = /(\d{4,6})(\d+\.\d{1,2}%)/g; 
var str = '"007007.13%"';
var subst = '$1|$2'; 

var result = str.replace(re, subs);
```

Demo in [Javascript](https://regex101.com/r/sC4pR4/2)